# One class classification using gee

Tags: python, gis, google-earth-engine, geemap

Is it possible to do classification like random forest classification with just survey points for one class. (kind of binary)

i tried usning ee.Classifier.smileCart().train but while .classify it shows error as EEException: Classifier training failed: 'Only one class.'.

Comment: No.  If there's only one class, then every sample is in that class.

Comment: cant i  classify a output with my one class which is predicted and rest as other class...like black and white...as i have survey points for one class only

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one class, then every sample is in that class. If you need the rest as other class then you need to select training samples for the 'others' as well.